# Fancybox Text Link Not Opening Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have been having a problem opening a fancybox in IE 7&8. It works fine in Chrome and FF. I have used this same type of implementation on another page and it works fine. So, I am guessing I am just missing something and need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it.

```
<script>
//booking info popup
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#biopopup").fancybox({
        'autoScale'         : false
    });
});
</script>
```

The link to open Fancybox:

```
<a id="biopopup" href="#bipop" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Booking Inquiry</a>
```

Content for the popup:

```
<div style="display:none">
        <div id="bipop" style="width:450px;height:500px;">
            <div id="formHeader">
                <h2>Booking Inquiry</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bookingForm">
                <form action="" method="" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="mainFields">
                        <input type="text" id="name" value="Full Name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Full Name') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Full Name'}">
                        <input type="text" id="organization" value="Organization" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Organization') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Organization'}">
                        <input type="text" id="email" value="Email Address" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email Address') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Email Address'}">
                        <input type="text" id="phone" value="Phone Number" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Phone Number') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Phone Number'}">
                        <input type="text" id="date" value="Desired Date" class="datepicker" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Desired Date') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Desired Date'}">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <input type="text" id="city" class="ccity" value="City" onfocus="if (this.value == 'City') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='City'}">
                            <input type="text" id="state" class="cstate" value="State" onfocus="if (this.value == 'State') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='State'}">
                            <input type="text" id="zip" class="czip" value="Zip" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Zip') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Zip'}">
                        </div>
                        <textarea id="comments" value="Comments" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Comments') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='Comments'}"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Info." class="button green">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the page: http://www.outreach.com/trial-test.aspx (click the "booking inquiry" button)

Comment: Check that your document has the proper `DOCTYPE` AND the `DOCTYPE` is the VERY, VERY first line of your document (no preceding spaces or commnets)

Comment: Yes, we have the doctype set for the whole site

Comment: I see, but it's not the very first line of the document ... there is a preceding space.

Comment: That may be true, but I have it working on this page for all browsers: http://www.outreach.com/campaigns/godquest-church-resources.aspx Click the "view Sean's bio" graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am a front end dev and usually don't have to deal with this, but our CMS is using asp and I forgot that all server controls must appear within a  tag. I am using a form in the popup and that created a conflict somewhere along the line. I took off form tag and it works now.